# How to get internal and external (sdcard) path with getExternalFilesDirs?

Tags: java, android, android-sdcard, android-external-storage, android-storage

I'm trying to get the paths to my **internal storage** and my **external storage** (removable sd card).

What I tried is this:

**Internal path**

```
path = getActivity().getExternalFilesDirs(null)[0].getAbsolutePath();
```

**External path**

```
path = getActivity().getExternalFilesDirs(null)[1].getAbsolutePath();
```

**Logcat**

Internal path returns:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.package./files
```

And with the help of **SubString** I managed to go to this path

```
/storage/emulated/0/
```

**Substring code**

```
int index = path.lastIndexOf("/Android/data/");
if (index > 0){
path =  path.substring(0, index);
Log.d(TAG, "value path0: " + path);
}
```

For the External path I did the same thing with **SubString** and it returns

```
/storage/3EC7-2342
```

Now what I'm not sure about is that it's ok for hardcoding the String **"/Android/data/"** because I'm not sure all devices have this String in their path and it may work on my device but maybe not on others.

Any other way for getting the **Absolute Path** from **internal** and **external storage (sdcard)**?

```
getActivity().getExternalFilesDirs(null)[0].getAbsolutePath();
```

**Logcat path value when I use the code above.**

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.package./files
```

It always returns a path that's too long, I need to get to the root of the internal and external memory.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you do not need substring code. You can use this. the following is for external path as you stated.

```
File file1 =  getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDirs(null)[1];
    while(!file1.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath().equals("/storage")) {

        file1 = file1.getParentFile();
        System.out.println(file1.getAbsolutePath());
    }
```

You can use similarly for internal path.

On second thought if in future "storage" also changes then following code should work.

```
String path = null;
    File file1 =  getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDirs(null)[1];
    while(!file1.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath().equals("/")) {

        file1 = file1.getParentFile();
        path = file1.getAbsolutePath();
        //System.out.println(file1.getAbsolutePath());
    }
    file1 =  getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDirs(null)[1];
    while(!file1.getParentFile().getAbsolutePath().equals(path)) {

        file1 = file1.getParentFile();
        System.out.println(file1.getAbsolutePath());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation of getExternalFilesDirs, I think it's ok to assume there'll always be an 'Android' folder after the root.

```
            //List of the storages
            List<File> storage = new ArrayList<>();
            File[] files = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(this, null);
            for (File file : files) {

                File parent = file.getParentFile();
                while (parent != null && !parent.getPath().endsWith(File.separator + "Android")) {

                    parent = parent.getParentFile();
                }
                if (parent!=null) // add to the list
                    storage.add(parent.getParentFile());
            }
```